# Why is CouchDB popular?

Tags: couchdb, nosql

Why is CouchDB so popular among non-relational databases?

Comment: Because it's soft, comfy and great for watching TV from?

Comment: I don't see anyone making a case for why this is anymore subjective than Why is C# suddenly so popular? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575513/why-is-c-suddenly-so-popular . Also, the questions was asked without pejoratives or all caps, so what is the case for labeling it argumentative?

Comment: @micahwittman You didn't see the poster's original question. Before I edited it he even included the word 'voldemort'. It was 1) silly 2) as asked, not a real question or at best subject and argumentative.

Comment: George, I see - good call, then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it's well promoted and quite good at what it does.

Answer (score 1):

As the late, great Eric Morecombe once observed, "Sofa, so good".

Answer (score 1):

> 1. It's **well-suited** to a good portion of web app development today where scalability and online/offline sysc are important (additionally, the strength of relational database's powerful data set analysis is often less important).
> 2. Arguably trivial **replication** built-in (replication is an afterthought in the lineage of most RDBMS ecosystems)
> 3. It's emerging as an **essential part of the stack** upon which desktop/cloud sync services in the open source arena are being built (see [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/)).

Because of #3, there's a decent marketing/awareness campaign behind it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty good introduction

http://www.linux-mag.com/cache/7597/1.html

Snip from article:

> You’ll often see the word “relax”
>   associated with CouchDB. That’s
>   because CouchDB tries to solve a lot
>   of the “hard problems” associated with
>   building a scalable distributed
>   document-oriented database. It does a
>   lot of heavy lifting for you so that
>   you can focus on building your
>   application without worrying too much
>   about administration or weird corner
>   cases.
>
> CouchDB also sports a very simple and
>   easy to understand RESTful API. This
>   should make for a very low barrier to
>   entry and stress-free development. As
>   we progress through the process of
>   using CouchDB, I think you’ll start to
>   realize that this motto is not just
>   “marketing speak.”